# Length of the result of SHA256 algo

Tags: mysql, sha256

I'm curious why the result of SHA256 can be saved within a `binary(32)`, but it needs a `varchar(64)` for the same result to be saved.

I mean, 256 bits are 32 bytes, so, saving inside a `binary(32)` makes perfect sense. But then why trying to save it in a `varchar` requires an extra byte for each byte?

Comment: Because you're receiving a hash which is essentially a number. That number, when represented in binary format is a sequence of 1s and 0s. However, when you want it to be represented via characters, for a hexadecimal number you require two characters. That's why binary output is 32 bytes and the character one is 64.

Comment: I still don't understand it. I'm trying to see the actual raw data, so I'm using Python's console. Writing ```a = 0b10101111``` will make ```a``` take a value of 175 (decimal). The representation of that same value in hexadecimal is 0xaf -> ```hex(0b10101111)```. So I have 8 bytes in binary, and I end with ```0xaf``` in hexadecimal. Where are all the missing bytes?

Comment: 1 byte = `10101111`. When you get raw output, 1 "character" of the raw output represents that `10101111`. There are 32 such "characters". They look garbled up when viewed directly via various editors, however you can store them inside a `binary` MySQL column. However, for that 1 byte, when converted to hexadecimal - it's character representation is `AF`. Therefore, it requires 2 ASCII characters to be represented.

Comment: No, sorry, I thought I understand it, but I think I don't. 8bites == 1 byte. So far so good. That byte can be represented an an ASCII character, which still has 1 byte length. So, 256bits are 32bytes, which can be represented as 32 ASCII characters. Where does the hex part come from and why? And how does hex matter in any way if I want to store the representation of those 32bytes as string (and not a hex numbers).

Comment: That 1 byte represents a number. Sure, that number can be represented in ASCII and you are correct. But what about code pages? Will the hash look the same in every code page? It won't, the codes above 127 are arbitrary and depend on the codepage and will be unreadable to most people. So it has to be interpreted as a number (since it is a number). But ASCII defines only 0-9, therefore 1 digit in your number = 1 byte. To represent `10101111` as `175` in ASCII = 3 bytes, since each digit is 1 character. Therefore, it's represented as a hex number. Hope this clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning and see what a cryptographic function is and what it's output actually is:

> A cryptographic hash function is a hash function, that is, an
>   algorithm that takes an arbitrary block of data and returns a
>   fixed-size bit string, the (cryptographic) hash value.

That means that we obtain sequence of 1s and 0s back. In order to save that sequence correctly, you have to use MySQL's `binary` data-type column since it doesn't save any data about how to represent the saved data to the user - there is no encoding associated with it. That means that when you try to view the data, you'll most likely see garbled characters since the GUI programs will attempt to represent the value stored as an ASCII-encoded string (which is wrong).

I'll skip the reasons why the hash value is represented as a number, but the point is that it is. And it's a hexadecimal number. Let's take the 1st byte that you used:

`10101111` = that's decimal `175` or hexadecimal `AF`.

Sure, you can represent ASCII `175` as something, it will most likely be a weird character depending on the codepage being used. Problem with ASCII is that codes above 127 are arbitrary, which lead to inventing codepages, which lead to inventing Unicode etc. so I'll skip it for now.

Point is, you can't rely on ASCII displaying `10101111` correctly in every scenario.
That means that `175` will have to be displayed using 3 bytes, not 1. Why? Because each character in `175` has to be displayed using its own byte.

That means that you can display your hash value as decimal number. That also means you can display your number as a hexadecimal number, which is significantly shorter to represent.

Let's take `10101111` again.

In decimal it's `175`, takes 3 bytes to show it on screen - 1 for `1`, 1 for `7` and 1 for `5`.
In hexadecimal it's `AF`, takes 2 bytes to show it on screen - significantly shorter.

Each byte when translated to hex number has at least 2 digits (there are leading zeroes). With decimal numbers that's not the case, so you know that every time you want to represent 1 byte as a hex number - you'd have at least 2 digits. Ergo, your message is fixed width, it uses digits 0-9, letters A-F which are at the same position in every ASCII code page, ergo they'll look the same.

So when you take `AF` and display it in ASCII, you need 1 byte for `A` and 1 byte for `F`.
There are 32 numbers, each has 2 digits, 32x2 = 64 bytes.

The only mistake you probably did was using `varchar(64)`. Using varchar for storing hashes is useless, if you know the hash width. Using `char` would be much better because you wouldn't waste that 1 byte that `varchar` column uses.

Hopefully, this clears it up a bit. It's actually more simple than it sounds :)

Comment: This answer is perfect! Now I really understand it.